# Accordion with pure javascript - only work with double click

Tags: javascript

I want to expand div on onclick event (**pure javascript**) by using accordion method as it has multiple level but it only works on double click. I want it to be in function instead of javascript onload.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

```js
function togglediv(){
 let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
 for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.classList.toggle("active");
   let panel=this.nextElementSibling;
   if(panel!==null){
    if (panel.style.display==="block") {
     panel.style.display="none";
    } else {
     panel.style.display="block";
    }
   }
   return false;
  });
 }
}
```

```css
.accordion, .subpanel-accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display:flex;
}

.panelaccordion {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="main-1" onclick="togglediv();">Level 1</div>
<div class="panelaccordion level2">
 <div class="accordion" id="sub-1" onclick="togglediv();">
  <div class="text-accordion">Level 2</div>
  <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid('sub-1');">Click level 2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="subpanel-accordion" id="subpanel-1">
  <div class="text-accordion">Level 3</div>
  <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getidsub('subpanel-1');">Click level 3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="accordion" id="sub-2" onclick="togglediv();">
  <div class="text-accordion">Level 2(2)</div>
  <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid('sub-2');">Click level 2(2)</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function then you won't be needing `addEventListener` as it already added `onlick` event:

```js
function toggle(item){
        item.classList.toggle("active");
            let panel=item.nextElementSibling;
            if(panel!==null){
                if (panel.style.display==="block") {
                    panel.style.display="none";
                } else {
                    panel.style.display="block";
                }
            }
            return false;
}
```

```css
.accordion, .subpanel-accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display:flex;
}

.panelaccordion {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="main-1" onclick="toggle(this);">Level 1</div>
<div class="panelaccordion level2">
    <div class="accordion" id="sub-1" onclick="toggle(this);">
        <div class="text-accordion">Level 2</div>
        <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid('sub-1');">Click level 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="subpanel-accordion" id="subpanel-1">
        <div class="text-accordion">Level 3</div>
        <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getidsub('subpanel-1');">Click level 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion" id="sub-2" onclick="toggle(this);">
        <div class="text-accordion">Level 2(2)</div>
        <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid('sub-2');">Click level 2(2)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `onclick="togglediv()` as you're already adding an event listener, so you can simply remove the `togglediv()` and just add the event listeners, like so:

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel !== null) {
      if (panel.style.display === "block") {
        panel.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        panel.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion,
.subpanel-accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
}

.panelaccordion {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="main-1">Level 1</div>
<div class="panelaccordion level2">
  <div class="accordion" id="sub-1">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 2</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid('sub-1');">
      Click level 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subpanel-accordion" id="subpanel-1">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 3</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getidsub('subpanel-1');">
      Click level 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion" id="sub-2">
    <div class="text-accordion">Level 2(2)</div>
    <div class="button-accordion" onclick="getid('sub-2');">
      Click level 2(2)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```